Positivity for a kinetic PDE
Let us consider the following kinetic equation:
$$ \partial_t f + v \cdot \partial_x f = \rho[f] \, M[T] - f $$
for a the phase space density $f=f(x,v,t)$ on $\mathbb{T}^1 \times \mathbb{R} \times (0, \infty)$ with respect to the positive initial condition
\begin{aligned}
0 < f(x, v, 0) &= f_0(x, v) \in L^1(\mathbb{T}^1 \times \mathbb{R}).
\end{aligned}
$\mathbb{T}^1$ is here the one-dimensional flat torus and $\rho[f](x,t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x,v,t) \, dv$ the macroscopic density. \begin{equation}
M[T](v) := \left( {\pi T} \right)^{-1/2} \exp \left( - \frac{|v|^2}{T} \right) > 0
\end{equation} with a given function $T(x,t) \geq c > 0$ is the well-known normalized Maxwell distribution.
A mild formulation is implicitly given by
\begin{equation} \label{reg nonlin kinetic}
f(x,v,t) = \mathrm{e}^{-t}f_0(x-vt,v) + \int_{0}^{t} \mathrm{e}^{s-t} \rho(x-v(t-s),s) M[T(x-v(t-s),s)](v) \, \mathrm{d}s.
\end{equation}
I would like to show the positivity of $f.$ But I have no idea how to perform here. My first thought was a Gronwall-like-argument. Would be very grateful for any help and hints!
(I posted this question earlier at MSE too: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4964824/positivity-for-a-kinetic-pde)

Which methods did you use so far to get other properties of the equations such as, for instance, well-posedness? One approach is to study the equation by means of $C_0$-semigroup theory. If you use the Dyson-Phillips series for perturbed $C_0$-semigroups, the positivity preserving property of the equation is quite straightforward.

@JochenGlueck Thanks for the answer. I used Picard-iteration and the contraction mapping theorem to show the existence of a local solution and then extended it to a global solution.
Is there maybe another possibility to see the positivity at least for small times?

Well, Picard iteration is more or less the same as the Dyson-Phillips series and should thus also give you the positivity (refering to semigroup theory just means that the theorems have already been proven in a general setting and can thus be cited from books instead of doing all the work again for each equation by hand). Anyway - when you try to also get the positivity from the Picard iteration, at which step do you encounter difficulties?

(Small remark: I think in your mild formulation, there is an $f$ missing under the integral.)

@JochenGlueck I don't see why and where I should miss an $f$ under integral? Could you perhaps elaborate on that?

My problem is, I would like to conclude the positivity of $f$ directly from the mild form. But it is a kind of circular argument since one needs first to establish that $\rho$ is non-negative, but that would, in turn, require that $f$ is non-negative. Unfortunately, I don't know the best way to proceed. Is there a standard approach for this?
I now checked some resources following your hint: The book by Engel/Nagel, "One-Parameter Semigroups for Linear Evolution Equations, p. 361 ff., Sect. 2 Semigroups for the Transport Equation" tackles a very similar problem.

However, in my case $M[T]$ depends on $t.$ I am therefore uncertain whether the results of semigroup theory can be directly applied here at all. (But actually I would prefer if I could do it "by hand" too.)

see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/478869/positivity-for-the-mild-solution-of-a-heat-equation-on-the-torus for the answer
